# Mathematics disciplines underpinning Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I have an undergrad degree in computational mathematics (though that was about 10 years ago), and spent my professional career in software development.

If I wanted to understand what's happening behind the scenes in ML, and not just blindly apply  equations, what disciplines would I need to study? Stochastic calculus? Something else?

A list of courses and recommended reading would be the most useful answer, with the goal being to learn over the course of a few years, not a quick fix.

Comment: I contend that even the machine learning researchers don't understand what's happening behind the scenes... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Books: Hastie et al., [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn) is a grad-level text, 745 pages, pdfs online.
See also [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning%20references) .

Learning by doing, in Python:
[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org)
has many algorithms, examples, solid code -- highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays in a lot of good CS programs there are classes directly on statistical/machine learning. The ones that have stats probably have a bit more of the underpinnings you are looking for. Also there are theoretical machine learning courses where they prove things like VC-dimension for classifiers and what it guarantees in terms of classification performance. Bishop has a good book "Pattern maching and machine learning" that's used at Carnegie Mellon University (one of the best ML programs) that explains a lot of ML concepts instead of just giving equations, and ties in Bayesian stats views.

Comment: ha. i bought that book a while ago, it's making a good bookend on my shelf right now. gotta fix that.

Comment: @kolosy The book is a reference book for our stochastic process course, but we start from Peebles and Brown&Hwang.

Comment: @Troy - this one? http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Signals-Applied-Filtering-Edition/dp/0471128392

Comment: @kolosy it has a 4th edition. I think our professor chose these books for a good reason, even the much hated Peebles book (I dont understand, I quite enjoyed it). He is an IEEE fellow and have taught the course for ages.